# Dynamically Dependent tables: Pulling data from MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am needing guidance in accessing parent tables, children tables, and children of children tables. I am needing help displaying tables through a php/jquery function. The goal is to display info through dynamically dependent tables.

I want to display the information in a drop down menu. With 6 main categories. When the user clicks an item in the main category it displays the child table. I am trying to display them through jquery. Here is an example website: [Example Site][1]

To test just save it as example.dbs and import it to MySQL and it will show. Here is my data:

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
   `c_id` tinyint(4) not null auto_increment,
   `category` varchar(30) not null,
   PRIMARY KEY (`c_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

INSERT INTO `category` (`c_id`, `category`) VALUES ('1', 'Books >');
INSERT INTO `category` (`c_id`, `category`) VALUES ('2', 'Electronics >');
INSERT INTO `category` (`c_id`, `category`) VALUES ('3', 'Furniture >');
INSERT INTO `category` (`c_id`, `category`) VALUES ('4', 'Clothing >');
INSERT INTO `category` (`c_id`, `category`) VALUES ('5', 'Jobs/Services >');
INSERT INTO `category` (`c_id`, `category`) VALUES ('6', 'Housing >');
```

Comment: can you give some exmaples of what you want? Otherwise there is no question really.

Comment: You need to be more specific with your question. What specifically are you looking for? You need help with how to use JOINS? You're looking for a jQuery plugin to automatically display data from a table? More detail please.

Comment: @ACobbs Yea, sorry for not being clear. I want to display the information in a drop down menu. With 6 main categories. When the user clicks an item in the main category it displays the child table. I am trying to display them through jquery. Here is live example i found in a website: [example website](http://www.encuentra24.com/panama-en/publish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but i'm supposing you are looking for querying the tables with the relationships. So mysql JOIN.

Example:

```
SELECT s3.subcategory3,s2.subcategory2,s1.subcategory,c.category FROM subcategory3 as s3 
LEFT JOIN subcategory2 as s2 ON s3.j_id=s2.j_id 
LEFT JOIN subcategory as s1 ON s2.s_id=s1.s_id 
LEFT JOIN category as c ON c. c_id=s1.c_id
```

The above will only return rows in subcategory3 that have parents, so only 4 rows (only 4 entries). if you want the full set, try this:

```
SELECT s3.subcategory3,s2.subcategory2,s1.subcategory,c.category FROM subcategory3 as s3 
RIGHT JOIN subcategory2 as s2 ON s3.j_id=s2.j_id 
RIGHT JOIN subcategory as s1 ON s2.s_id=s1.s_id 
RIGHT JOIN category as c ON c. c_id=s1.c_id
ORDER BY subcategory3,subcategory2,subcategory,category ASC
```

Comment: thank you. I am getting closer to my goal thanks to your help.